# Change drop folder for VS2017 NuGet Package build

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

In VS2017, when you tick the option on the *Project Properties -> Package* page to **Generate NuGet package on build**, it drops the resultant package somewhere under the output folder, e.g. under Debug somewhere.

Is it possible to change this to a specific folder, or better yet, somewhere specified by an environment variable?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to change this to a specific folder, or better yet, somewhere specified by an environment variable?

You can use the property "`PackageOutputPath`" to change the default package`s folder:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageOutputPath>Specific Folder Path</PackageOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You could add the options of setting this value via a `/p:` argument or environment variable.

Comment: @Martin Could you explain your comment? I have LOTS of projects and want to collect all nuget packages in local folders while in development. An environment variable would be great since multiple developers use the code on their individual VMs.

Comment: You can set `PackageOutputPath` as environment variable (any msbuid property) or create a Directory.Build.props file in your folder hierarchy that contains a property group with this variable, e.g. set to `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)packages`